# Im working on this game with pygame and Im trying to add animated power up and i've run into trouble

Tags: python, animation, pygame

SO I'm making this game and my trying to add an animated powerup/health pack which heals the player. I tried reusing some code which I used to make an explosion animation but the way I've don't is obviously wrong and I need some help.

My Git hub below:
https://github.com/Sirbraindamage/Games-and-Project.git

This is the code explosion animation code I tried to adapt into the animated powerup

[image]

What it does it loops through all of the images when its called in main. it also scales the images to two sizes. the larger size it for when all bullets hit an NPC and the smaller one for when the NPC hits the player.

[image]

This code is similar to the one above as it loop through the images but tried incorporating it into a sprite to make a powerup but it didn't work.

[image]

This I how I tried to incorporate it into the sprite which didn't work...

[image]

This is an image of the error which appear when the powerup tries to spawn

[image]

This is the code that's used to spawn the powerup...

The rest of the codes in the Github (tell if it works or not I'm very new to GitHub)

So if anyone can find out how to add an animated powerup which heals the player I would be much appreciated. Also, There's a health variable under the player class if you're looking for it.

Also full code on Github

weird visual bug:
[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code! Paste the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a attribute `frame` and read the first image in the constructor:

```py
self.image = powerup_anim['HP'][0]
self.frame = 0
```

Change the image in `update`. Read and image from the list dependent to the attribute `frame` and increment `frame`:

```py
self.image = powerup_anim['HP'][self.frame]
self.frame += 1
if self.frame > len(powerup_anim['HP'])
    self.frame = 0
```

class `Pow`:

```py
class Pow(py.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center):
        py.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = powerup_anim['HP'][0]
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = py.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 75

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        # py.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)

    def update(self):

        now = py.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.image = powerup_anim['HP'][self.frame]
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame >= len(powerup_anim['HP']):
                self.kill()

        # kill if moved of screen
        if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT + 20 or self.rect.top < -20:
            self.kill()
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20 or self.rect.left < -20:
            self.kill()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this was actually pretty similar to as I had it when TheBigKahuna told me to refuse the explosion code (i have used your code #sorry Kahuna). But I've run into an issue I've got this error `IndexError: list index out of range` in this line `self.image = powerup_anim['HP'][self.frame]` i find this weird as my for loop should only be looping four times right?

Comment: I've tried looking around but I don't know why I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range` error it should only be looping through the 4 images

Comment: I've got these weird visual bugs when I kill an NPC. These white dots aren't the bullets but they spawn when i kill the NPC now... (see in the post above)

Comment: how do you die so fast?

Comment: @SirBraindmage Apparently I'm a bad gamer. My son laughs at me, when I play things  like this.

Comment: Hahahaha. That's funny but could you have a look at the post I've added its an image of visual big I'm pretty sure these white dots are explosion animations and I've looked at the code and I don't see any difference  but it's now broken.

Comment: Yeah I did forget the self.kill() but the animation doesn't seem to be working it just flashes white dot then dispears

Comment: By the looks of it, it's only playing the first image of the explosion animation

Comment: @SirBraindmage Yes. Similar as  `Explosion`. By the way, what does not work - `Pow`, `Explosion`, both?

Comment: sorry I didn't clarify only the explosion animation isn't working

Comment: @SirBraindmage What did you change in the class `Explosion`?

Comment: Ok don't mind me I'm retarded I completely forgot a removed some line of code as I was testing something I've added it back it is working sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

The error says `list object has no attribute get_rect`. meaning, its not the image but the list of images. so to get the image, you can just get the first one

```
self.image = powerup_anim['HP'][0] #get first image
```

Also the code for the explosion seems fine to reuse. You could even make one general class to do the animations, but this is kinda a extra for experts and is not needed

Comment: that only gets the first image and doesn't animate it just stay's on the first image.

Comment: @SirBraindmage yes, you will need to change the `self.image` to the next frame manually like you did with the explosion, If you look at the explosion class, you can see it also uses `self.image = explosion_anim[self.size'][0]` too